# How to compute/plot efficient frontiers per time period in one graph in R?

Tags: r

Currently we compute and sort data of stocks (X1 to X10). Historical data is stored in Excel and R for the time period 1950-1980, 1980-1999 and for 1950-1999.

The dataset:

```
       date     X1      X2    X3    X4    X5     X6   X7    X8    X9   X10
1   1950-01-01  5.92   6.35  4.61  4.08  5.47  3.90  2.35  1.49  2.27  0.82
2   1950-02-01  2.43   2.16  2.10  1.58 -0.05  1.14  1.51  1.52  2.02  1.12
3   1950-03-01 -0.81   0.21 -1.67 -0.02 -0.79  0.18 -0.22  1.03  0.12  1.75
4   1950-04-01  5.68   6.45  5.41  5.94  6.10  5.87  3.82  3.34  3.44  3.97
5   1950-05-01  3.84   1.60  1.64  3.33  2.54  2.12  4.46  2.83  3.82  4.75
6   1950-06-01 -9.88 -10.56 -8.02 -7.86 -7.27 -7.44 -7.13 -7.76 -6.32 -5.04
7   1950-07-01  9.09   8.76  7.31  5.88  3.84  4.61  3.09  3.07  1.41  0.42
598 1999-10-01 -0.95  -1.88 -1.25 -0.52  1.65  0.72  5.41  4.38  5.58  6.59
599 1999-11-01 11.57   9.15  8.17  7.14  6.15  4.95  5.78  4.21  1.55  2.15
600 1999-12-01 12.32  14.97  9.29 11.77 11.09  5.89 11.88 11.26  6.23  5.64
```

The main question is, we would like to compute/plot efficient frontiers for these 4 time periods to see how the efficient frontier has evolved in 1 graph. Are there ways to do this in R?

**The efficient frontier is the set of optimal portfolios that offers the highest expected return for a defined level of risk or the lowest risk for a given level of expected return.**

**In modern portfolio theory, the efficient frontier (or portfolio frontier) is an investment portfolio which occupies the 'efficient' parts of the risk-return spectrum. Formally, it is the set of portfolios which satisfy the condition that no other portfolio exists with a higher expected return but with the same standard deviation of return.**

So, how would one go about computing this in R?

dput sample data (first 50 rows)

```
> dput(head(data,50))

structure(list(X__1 = structure(c(-631152000, -628473600, -626054400, 
-623376000, -620784000, -618105600, -615513600, -612835200, -610156800, 
-607564800, -604886400, -602294400, -599616000, -596937600, -594518400, 
-591840000, -589248000, -586569600, -583977600, -581299200, -578620800, 
-576028800, -573350400, -570758400, -568080000, -565401600, -562896000, 
-560217600, -557625600, -554947200, -552355200, -549676800, -546998400, 
-544406400, -541728000, -539136000, -536457600, -533779200, -531360000, 
-528681600, -526089600, -523411200, -520819200, -518140800, -515462400, 
-512870400, -510192000, -507600000, -504921600, -502243200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), X__2 = c(5.92, 2.43, -0.81, 5.68, 
3.84, -9.88, 9.09, 4.93, 3.99, -0.5, 3.09, 15.77, 8.22, 0.36, 
-7.36, 3.84, -2.81, -7.12, 3.57, 6.59, 1.04, -1.41, -1.42, -0.53, 
1.86, -3.25, 0.68, -4.4, 0.57, 2.5, -0.36, -0.74, -1.11, -0.58, 
3.22, 0.33, 5.01, 2.75, -1.25, -2.13, 1.3, -4.42, 0.25, -5.56, 
-4.09, 2.71, 2.01, -3.15, 8.48, -0.16), X__3 = c(6.35, 2.16, 
0.21, 6.45, 1.6, -10.56, 8.76, 4.63, 3.52, -1.2, 3.36, 10.98, 
8.41, 0.81, -4.01, 3.56, -4.27, -6.11, 4.7, 5.3, 2.73, -3.07, 
-0.13, 0.6, 1.1, -2.77, 2.37, -4.5, 1.87, 3.18, 1.51, 0.43, -1.91, 
-1.52, 4.91, 1.43, 3.4, 3.03, -2.25, -2, 0.34, -4.75, 2.24, -6.53, 
-1.87, 1.97, 1.78, -2.96, 7.38, 0.43), X__4 = c(4.61, 2.1, -1.67, 
5.41, 1.64, -8.02, 7.31, 4.56, 5.18, -0.46, 3.52, 10.78, 8.46, 
0.28, -4.88, 4.26, -3.25, -6.76, 6.78, 4.99, 3.86, -2.57, 0.59, 
0.16, 1.75, -2.04, 2.49, -5.29, 1.76, 2.88, 0.76, 0.67, -1.67, 
-1.45, 5.69, 2.95, 3.66, 1.15, -1.58, -2.34, 0.51, -3.82, 0.72, 
-6.25, -2.33, 3.1, 2.19, -2.63, 7.3, 1.82), X__5 = c(4.08, 1.58, 
-0.02, 5.94, 3.33, -7.86, 5.88, 4.68, 5.99, 0.75, 2.68, 9.29, 
8, 1.08, -3.13, 4.21, -3.35, -5.01, 5.77, 4.85, 2.73, -3.44, 
0.27, 1.56, 1.62, -2.35, 2.93, -4.62, 2.36, 2.56, 0.86, 0.16, 
-1.8, -2.04, 5.12, 2.72, 3.21, 1.21, -2.17, -1.84, 0.32, -3.63, 
1.47, -5.16, -0.65, 3.33, 1.34, -1.36, 6.24, 1.19), X__6 = c(5.47, 
-0.05, -0.79, 6.1, 2.54, -7.27, 3.84, 6.29, 4.46, -0.24, 2.42, 
6.12, 8.63, 0.88, -3.31, 4.56, -2.14, -5.62, 5.73, 5.36, 2.44, 
-1.88, 0.83, 0.65, 1.47, -1.81, 2.31, -4.48, 2.56, 2.69, 0.9, 
0.34, -0.62, -1.58, 6.59, 0.86, 3.58, 1.92, -1.85, -2.79, 0.7, 
-3.4, 1.26, -5.26, -1.18, 4.26, 1.35, -0.97, 6.66, 1.77), X__7 = c(3.9, 
1.14, 0.18, 5.87, 2.12, -7.44, 4.61, 4.57, 6.14, -0.84, 4.22, 
8.37, 7.44, 0.69, -4.26, 4.13, -2.24, -6.75, 5.81, 4.35, 1.98, 
-2.87, 0.93, 0.61, 1.27, -2.18, 2.97, -4.09, 2.27, 2.96, 1.16, 
-0.38, -2.37, -0.71, 5.53, 2.45, 1.3, 0.31, -0.47, -2.03, 0.14, 
-3.26, 1.79, -5.5, -1.47, 4.18, 1.96, -1.35, 7.06, 1.69), X__8 = c(2.35, 
1.51, -0.22, 3.82, 4.46, -7.13, 3.09, 5.01, 5.84, -1.05, 3.81, 
7.54, 6.46, 0.71, -3.56, 4.42, -1.87, -4.52, 7.3, 3.66, 2.11, 
-2.92, 2.25, 2.17, 1.32, -1.71, 3.17, -4.63, 2.59, 3.89, 0.49, 
0.21, -1.71, -1.18, 4.95, 3.21, 1.41, 0.89, -1.02, -2.89, 0.59, 
-2.67, 1.47, -4.62, -0.69, 4.07, 2.83, -1.44, 6.11, 1.58), X__9 = c(1.49, 
1.52, 1.03, 3.34, 2.83, -7.76, 3.07, 3.72, 6.21, -1.66, 3.46, 
6.14, 7.17, 2.13, -3.19, 4.59, -2.65, -3.5, 7.43, 3.5, 2.41, 
-2.73, 1.35, 1.97, 1.72, -1.8, 4.06, -5.35, 2.57, 3.14, 1.89, 
-0.86, -1.73, -0.95, 6.07, 1.73, 1.09, 0.37, -1.34, -2.48, 0.31, 
-3.2, 1.34, -4.99, -0.18, 4.35, 3.03, 0.09, 5.65, 2.39), X__10 = c(2.27, 
2.02, 0.12, 3.44, 3.82, -6.32, 1.41, 4.54, 5.55, -0.97, 3.8, 
5.69, 5.65, 1.78, -2.6, 4.21, -1.29, -2.63, 7.15, 3.52, 1.85, 
-2.32, 0.96, 2.74, 1.9, -2.6, 3.83, -4.31, 3.15, 2.76, 0.93, 
-0.39, -1.86, -1.57, 7.05, 2.36, -0.33, -0.23, -0.54, -2.6, 0.61, 
-2.37, 2.12, -3.76, 0.47, 3.98, 3.03, 0.2, 5.63, 1.26), X__11 = c(0.82, 
1.12, 1.75, 3.97, 4.75, -5.04, 0.42, 4.96, 4.32, 0.25, 2.26, 
4.71, 5.05, 1.63, -1.53, 5.12, -2.59, -1.92, 6.89, 4.48, -0.09, 
-2.49, 0.26, 4.03, 1.37, -2.82, 4.95, -5.1, 3.4, 4.29, 0.89, 
-1.06, -2.18, -0.31, 5.76, 3.32, -1.04, -0.63, -1.78, -2.97, 
0.55, -1.3, 2.75, -4.47, 0.48, 4.83, 2.85, 0.27, 4.4, 1.93)), .Names = c("date", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", 
"X9", "X10"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This may give an idea: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-finance-using-r-efficient-frontier-and-capm-part-1/

Comment: @MichaelChirico see edit!

Comment: @SerhatCevikel, Thank you! It is a beautiful example, just what I need. However, this example does focus on just 3 assets, while I have a plenty of it, 10 stocks.. The code is not very efficient to edit for 10 stocks... as you see that even the author of the example needs to add lines of code to just add a third asset...

Answer (score 0):

After a few correpondence via the comments with @Jonathan, I widened the example data from 3 columns to 12 columns with some sampling. And the code at the "With short-selling" section at [the blog](https://datashenanigan.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/a-gentle-introduction-to-finance-using-r-efficient-frontier-and-capm-part-1/) scales well for 10K observations:

```
# using code at:
# https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-finance-using-r-efficient-frontier-and-capm-part-1/
# https://datashenanigan.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/a-gentle-introduction-to-finance-using-r-efficient-frontier-and-capm-part-1/

library(data.table)

calcEFParams <- function(rets)
{

    retbar <- colMeans(rets, na.rm = T)
    covs <- var(rets, na.rm = T) # calculates the covariance of the returns
    invS <- solve(covs)
    i <- matrix(1, nrow = length(retbar))

    alpha <- t(i) %*% invS %*% i
    beta <- t(i) %*% invS %*% retbar
    gamma <- t(retbar) %*% invS %*% retbar
    delta <- alpha * gamma - beta * beta

    retlist <- list(alpha = as.numeric(alpha),
                    beta = as.numeric(beta),
                    gamma = as.numeric(gamma),
                    delta = as.numeric(delta))

    return(retlist)
}

# load data
link <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DavZim/Efficient_Frontier/master/data/mult_assets.csv"

df <- data.table(read.csv(link))
df2 <- df[,lapply(.SD, sample),]
df3 <- cbind(df, df2)
df4 <- df3[,lapply(.SD, sample),]
df5 <- cbind(df3, df4)
```

Now loading the microbenchmark package, the performance is as such:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(calcEFParams(df5), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 calcEFParams(df5) 2.692514 2.764053 2.795127 2.777547 2.805447 3.024349    10
```

It seems that David Zimmermann's code is scalable and efficient enough!

Comment: Which example data? Mine or the one provided at the particular website with the available source codes?

Comment: The one provided at the blog and with 10K rows (and my implementation has 12 columns in df5). I think yours has 600 rows and 10 columns?